# Getting unique items from a list

Tags: c#, list, unique

What is the fastest / most efficient way of getting all the distinct items from a list?

I have a `List<string>` that possibly has multiple repeating items in it and only want the unique values within the list.

Comment: The title of this question is misleading. Selecting unique items is about selecting items that occur just once in the list, against selecting each distinct element,once.
Given `["A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D"]`, unique items would return `["A","B"]`, whereas distinct items would return `["A", "B", "C", "D"]`.

Comment: @EduardoPignatelli Quite picky, but the question could be reworded unambiguously. The intent of this question as normally encountered means: "Given a list of values, how do I get a list of those values without duplicating any?"

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Use a [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx). For example:

```
var items = "A B A D A C".Split(' ');
var unique_items = new HashSet<string>(items);
foreach (string s in unique_items)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

prints

```
A
B
D
C
```

Comment: Must agree; others solve the problem, yours solves the cause :)

Comment: A `HashSet` won't maintain any ordering, which may or may not be an issue for the OP.

Comment: thanks guys, I don't require the items to be ordered. This works great.

Answer (score 199):

You can use the [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) method to return an `IEnumerable<T>` of distinct items:

```
var uniqueItems = yourList.Distinct();
```

And if you need the sequence of unique items returned as a `List<T>`, you can add a call to [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx):

```
var uniqueItemsList = yourList.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: The OP was looking for a fast/efficient method. This is not it. Calling `yourList.Distinct().ToList()` requires two full iterations over the enumerable, and additionally is based off `IEqualityComparer`, which is slower than `GetHashCode`.

Comment: Is this faster/more efficient than a HashSet<T>? I don't think so. Not bothering to downvote, though :-)

Comment: @Noldorin, @Vinay: *If* the OP needs the distinct items returned as a `List` then they'll need to call `ToList`, regardless of whether they use `Distinct` or construct a `HashSet`. Having said that, you're right that a `HashSet` will probably have better performance than `Distinct` in most circumstances.

Comment: @Noldorin: I know this is old, but it shows up easily on Google and you're wrong (at least, as of .NET 4 - I haven't checked in older versions). yourList.Distinct().ToList() performs one enumeration, new HashSet<T>(yourList).ToList() performs two. And the implementations of HashSet and Distinct's internal Set class are almost identical. They both use GetHashCode, and they both use IEqualityComparers (which they have to, as equal hashcodes don't (in general) guarantee equal objects).

Comment: @Noldorin: How would a performance benchmark make any argument for or against what I said?  You can verify what I said by pulling up System.Linq.Enumerable.DistinctIterator<T> and System.Linq.Set<T> in Reflector (or other .NET decompiler), independent of relative performance.

Comment: @IainM: Sorry, you're right. I was reading into your post and taking the implication that they are similar in speed. I am still very interested if they actually are. I suspect the difference is still there, though it has possibly gone down since .NET 4.0.

Comment: Note that `Distinct` is an extension method and lives in `System.Linq` namespace. `public static IEnumerable<TSource> Distinct<TSource> (this IEnumerable<TSource> source)`

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336761.aspx#distinct1) extension method from LINQ

Answer (score 5):

Apart from the `Distinct` extension method of LINQ, you could use a [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) object that you initialise with your collection. This is most likely more efficient than the LINQ way, since it uses hash codes (`GetHashCode`) rather than an `IEqualityComparer`).

In fact, if it's appropiate for your situation, I would just use a `HashSet` for storing the items in the first place.

Comment: A `HashSet` won't maintain any ordering, which may or may not be an issue for the OP.

Comment: @Luke: Even so, ordering would have no meaning after calling `Distinct`...

Comment: @Luke: The question asks about fastest/most efficient, and doesn't require ordering to be maintained.

Comment: @Noldorin: Why not? `Distinct` should/does iterate the list in order (although I'm not sure if that's actually guaranteed in any spec).

Comment: @Luke: Oh, I was thinking of indexing really. And anyway, efficiency was mentioned in the OP, while order wasn't (though that's open question) - `HashSet` is the way to go if you want good performance.

Answer (score 5):

In .Net 2.0 I`m pretty sure about this solution:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Distinct<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
     List<T> uniques = new List<T>();
     foreach (T item in source)
     {
         if (!uniques.Contains(item)) uniques.Add(item);
     }
     return uniques;
}
```

Comment: *Please* use a collection with faster random access than List, such as a Dictionary or HashSet. Because currently, if `source` contains 100,000 items with many duplicates, then in every one of the 100,000 iterations you will be scanning a list on the order of 100,000 items, meaning you are scanning on the order of `100,000 * 100,000` items. Quadratic time complexity can become quite slow.