# How to get unique record in list

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of string having currencies in it, for example the size is 1000. I want list if string of all the unique currencies out of 1000 records.

Now its like -

```
INR
USD
JPY
USD
USD
INR
```

and I want List of string like -

```
INR
USD
JPY
```

only unique record

Preferably without using Linq

Comment: Why don't you want to use LINQ?

Comment: The product where I am using it doesn't support linq

Comment: @nitendrajain Please clarify...?

Comment: What is the framework version you are using ? is it .Net 3.0 or lower ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:

I missed the part *"preferably without using LINQ"*, 
You may try the following if you are using .Net framework 2.0 or you don't want to use LINQ.

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "abc", "abc", "ab", "def", "abc", "def" };
list.Sort();
int i = 0;
while (i < list.Count - 1)
{
    if (list[i] == list[i + 1])
        list.RemoveAt(i);
    else
        i++;
}
```

<strike>use `Distinct()`</strike>

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "abc", "abc", "ab", "def", "abc","def" };
List<string> uniqueList = list.Distinct().ToList();
```

The `uniqueList` will contain `3` items `"abc","ab","def"`

Remember to include: `using System.Linq;` at the top

Comment: -1 "*Preferably without using Linq*"

Comment: @James, missed the part for not using LINQ, have modified my answer accordingly

Comment: @Habib downvote revoked :) However, I would recommend using a `HashSet` over creating another list, sorting it etc (if possible, not sure which version of .NET the OP is on).

Comment: Caution: This modifies the original list and might not be what the OP intended but might aswell be exactly what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

`HashSet<T>` is what you're looking for. Reference [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx):

> The `HashSet<T>` class provides high-performance set operations. A set is a collection that **contains no duplicate elements**, and whose elements are in no particular order.

Note that the [`HashSet<T>.Add(T item)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005.aspx) returns a `bool` -- `true` if the item was added to the collection; `false` if the item was already present.

[HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) will work for you if using .NET 3.5 or above, no Linq involved.

```
var hash = new HashSet<string>();
var collectionWithDup = new [] {"one","one","two","one","two","zero"}; 

foreach (var str in collectionWithDup)
{
    hash.Add(str);
}

// Here hash (of type HashSet) will be containing the unique list
```

If you are not using .NET 3.5, simple use this piece of code:

```
List<string> newList = new List<string>();

foreach (string s in list)
{
   if (!newList.Contains(s))
      newList.Add(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not store these in a [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) and then read out from that. The set will only contain unique values.

Comment: Yes, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388361/getting-all-unique-items-in-a-c-sharp-list

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have these values stored in array or ArrayList there are 2 ways:

first way

```
var UniqueValues = nonUnique.Distinct().ToArray();
```

second way

```
//create a test arraylist of integers
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9};
ArrayList arrList = new ArrayList(arr);
//use a hashtable to create a unique list
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
foreach (int item in arrList) {
//set a key in the hashtable for our arraylist value - leaving the hashtable value      empty
    ht.Item[item] = null;
}
//now grab the keys from that hashtable into another arraylist
ArrayList distincArray = new ArrayList(ht.Keys);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `Distinct` Extension Method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
  public static IEnumerable<T> Distinct<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
  {
    var distinctList = new List<T>();

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
      if (!distinctList.Contains(item)) distinctList.Add(item);
    }

    return distinctList;
  }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var list = new List<string>() {"INR", "USD", "JPY", "USD", "USD", "INR"};
  var distinctList = list.Distinct();
  foreach(var item in distinctList) Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Which will yield:

```
INR
USD
JPY
```