# How to take count of unique sub-string occurrence

Tags: c#

I have the following `Guids` received from client in an array.

Question: How i can take `count` of the `unique` `Guids` showing after `'_'` from the following array.

```
0: "5146d57a-701d-e511-82ee-303a64efb676_6544d57a-701d-e511-82ee-303a64efb676"
1: "5546d57a-701d-e511-82ee-303a64efb676_6544d57a-701d-e511-82ee-303a64efb676"
2: "5346d57a-701d-e511-82ee-303a64efb676_6544d57a-701d-e511-82ee-303a64efb676"

3: "5146d57a-701d-e511-82ee-303a64efb676_6644d57a-701d-e511-82ee-303a64efb676"
4: "5546d57a-701d-e511-82ee-303a64efb676_6644d57a-701d-e511-82ee-303a64efb676"
5: "5346d57a-701d-e511-82ee-303a64efb676_6644d57a-701d-e511-82ee-303a64efb676"

6: "5146d57a-701d-e511-82ee-303a64efb676_6744d57a-701d-e511-82ee-303a64efb676"
7: "5546d57a-701d-e511-82ee-303a64efb676_6744d57a-701d-e511-82ee-303a64efb676"
8: "5346d57a-701d-e511-82ee-303a64efb676_6744d57a-701d-e511-82ee-303a64efb676"
```

Comment: post what have you tried and the problem you are facing instead of asking for a readymade solution.

Comment: Solution alredy provided : http://stackoverflow.com/q/1388361/3711660

Comment: A dictionary and string.split would come in handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input is some implementation of `IEnumerable<string>` (e.g. array or list):

```
int count = input.Select(line => line.Split('_').Last()).Distinct().Count();
```

This splits each line at the `_` character, takes only the last part and counts the distinct parts.

Comment: Implementation is public List<Guid> Ids { get; set; }

Comment: Your answer shows a list of two guids per line, that can't be a `List<Guid>`.

Comment: you're right. I change implementation from Guid to string and it gives the require result. thanks