# C# ToList performance and alternative ways

Tags: c#

I have a big dictionary and a list (myList). I want to keep the items in myList only if there is an item in my dictionary with the same Title. The problem is that the initialisation of titleList takes long time (2-3 sec). Is there any better way to do that?

```
var dictionary = r.MyFunction.Where(a condition);
var titleList = dictionary.Select(x => x.Value.Title).ToList()

myList = productsTemp.Where(x => titleList.Contains(x.Title)).ToList();
```

Comment: This may add some speed-up's `var titleList = new HashSet<string>(dictionary.Select(x => x.Value))`

Comment: Are you sure it is not the `myList` creation that takes time?

Comment: Did you try removing the call of the `ToList` method in the second line? I think is not necessary, in the next line you are going to use the `IEnumerable<T>.Contains` method

Comment: What is the target timing you are trying to achieve in list creation?

Comment: you can combine all to one condition   myList = productsTemp.Where(x => r.MyFunction.Where(p=> p.key ==  condition && P.Value.Title == x.Title).ToList();

Comment: I think that would take forever (> 2 seconds).

Comment: Is a ToDictionary() trailer missing from line 1?  Is the dictionary actually used elsewhere (not shown in example)?

Comment: Your sample code is incomplete. Please provide complete, compiling sample code. E.g. what is MyFunction (property? of what type?). All answers are just guesswork without this information.

Comment: `Where` does not return a `Dictionary`, so labelling your first `var` as `dictionary` is very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, HashSets may optimize the distinct of string as list is not required to be ordered [Getting unique items from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388361/getting-unique-items-from-a-list)

and as for the code, it should work like this :

```
    var items = r.MyFunction.Where(a condition).Select(p => p.Value.Title);
    var titleList = new HashSet<string>(items);
    myList = productsTemp.Where(x => titleList.Contains(x.Title)).ToList();
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: constructor call is now outside.

Comment: Doesn't this create a new `HashSet<T>` for every iteration of product in `productsTemp` (thus being `O(m*n)`)? Extracting the constructor call would help a lot, performance-wise.